# Error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image

Tags: python, pycharm, argparse

I dont deeply understand about the meaning of argparse. And when i tested with this code, it always this error:

```
usage: test1.py [-h] -i IMAGE
test1.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image
```

This is my code:

```
# (1) import the necessary packages
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2

# (2) construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, help="path to the input image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# (3) load the image, convert it to grayscale, blur it slightly,
# and threshold it
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)    cv2.imwrite('C:\\Users\\Hoang Cao Chuyen\\Downloads\\shapes.png', gray)

blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
cv2.imwrite('C:\\Users\\Hoang Cao Chuyen\\Downloads\\shapes.png', blurred)

thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
cv2.imwrite('C:\\Users\\Hoang Cao Chuyen\\Downloads\\shapes.png', thresh)

# find contours in the thresholded image
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
```

Comment: What is your input in command line?  As you set `required=True`, you need to input like `test1.py -i image` and `test1.py image` will raise error.

Comment: how exactly did you test this?  What's the `image` value, and how did you provide it?

Comment: With `pycharm` you have to specify command line arguments in some extra window.  You can't just push the `run` button.  I don't know why many new users miss this.  Doesn't the IDE docs explain how to run scripts with arguments?

Comment: thank you guys. You're so kind to answer me. As I said first, i didnt understand the extreme meaning of argparse.I read some documents but i still cannot.

Comment: The input of path is a image from my C:/ path, but the '-image','-i', i dont know where it is from?

Comment: It's the job of someone using this program to provide that command-line argument. So it comes from the user, if they're using your program correctly.

Comment: Voting to reopen, the "duplicate" question is about how arguments are parsed when passing a list of strings to an `ArgumentParser`.  The error message happens to be the same but the root cause is completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code adds a required flag `-i` or `--image`:

```
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, help="path to the input image")
```

This means the script expects you to specify the `-i` or `--image` flag with an argument, like this:

```
python test1.py --image C:\path\to\image.png
```

If you want the image path to be a positional argument instead, you can change that line of code to this:

```
ap.add_argument("image", help="path to the input image")
```

Then you can call your script like this:

```
python test1.py C:\path\to\image.png
```

Relevant documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#name-or-flags

Comment: As your suggestion and with my understanding, I tried to code : python test1.py --image C:\pythonProject\venv\bill_gates.jfif in my Terminal ,but it failed.

Comment: @ChuyênHoàng What error message did you get?  Make sure that `python` is on your path or refers to the correct Python executable, and `test1.py` should be the path to your script file.

Comment: After finding out something on the Youtube, I fixed the error. The answer is the same as yours. Thank you

Comment: Another error is in my code, not in argparse anymore